# Why do you need "total answer score of 5" to suggest tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tag-synonyms, privileges

I am not so good at answering questions, but I do read a lot of them and I usually figure out what common synonyms are used for a concept.

I would like to improve Stack Overflow by suggesting some tag synonyms, but alas, I do not have the "Answer Score" in the tag needed to suggest.

I would like to request that another (higher) question score be added to suggesting tag synonyms.

Or maybe a "if you are over 15,000 rep and you have X number of questions with X number of upvotes in a tag" then you can suggest tag synonyms.

I am just looking for some way for us question askers to help improve the tags.

Remember, this is just to suggest.  They still have to be voted on and approved by 4 other people.

Comment: This is especially important on the beta sites where there are a lot more tags relative to the number of users, and a lot fewer people who can do anything about them (rather than retagging the dozens of tags that only are attached to 1-2 questions, bumping them to the top of the active questions, and only a temporary fix as users with 150 rep can add new ones on a whim)